# Nested quoting in bash

Tags: bash

I'm connecting to a remote server via SSH:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/pk.pem user@server
```

and then, on that server, open bash within a Docker container:

```
docker exec -it $(docker ps | grep ecs-worker-low | cut -d ' ' -f1) bash
```

This works fine. *(Note that I need to get the container ID like this. I'm not able to name the container.)*

I would like to combine the two commands, so that I only run one command and get the shell within the container. This can be done with something like this:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/pk.pem user@server -t "bash -c 'docker exec -it $(docker ps | grep ecs-worker-low | cut -d ' ' -f1) bash'"
```

However this doesn't work because of the nested single quotes. I haven't found any way around this. Can you please help me? Thank you.

Comment: Your current command is running `docker ps` on the local machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can avoid the use of `cut` with `--filter` and `--format`

```
ssh -t -i ~/.ssh/pk.pem user@serve 'docker exec -it $(docker ps --filter ancestor=ecs-worker-low --format {{.ID}}) bash'
```

Comment: This is a great point, thank you Philippe. This solves the issue with quotes, however, as @William Pursell pointed out in the comment, the $() command actually runs on my local machine, so I can't use it that way.

Comment: This is resolved by escaping the dollar sign: \$() and it works :)

Comment: With the single quote in front of `docker exec`, `$()` runs on remote machine.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easiest to use a heredoc:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/pk.pem user@server -t << \EOF
docker exec -it $(docker ps | grep ecs-worker-low | cut -d ' ' -f1)
EOF
```

Make sure you use a non-interpolating heredoc.  If you omit the backslash on the initial delimiter, the process substitution will be made on the local host.

Comment: Doesn't this cause the `bash` shell to (indirectly) inherit its standard input from the here document as well?

Comment: @chepner Yes, but that shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Swap the quotes:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/pk.pem user@server -t 'bash -c "docker exec -it $(docker ps | grep ecs-worker-low | cut -d " " -f1) bash"'
```

All the double quotes are literal characters as far as `ssh` is concerned, and the command substitution creates a new context so that the first inner quote does not close the first outer quote. That said...

... Simplifying matters, you likely don't need the outer `bash`; `ssh` can run `docker` for you directly:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/pk.pem user@server -t 'docker exec -it $(docker ps | grep ecs-worker-low | cut -d " " -f1) bash'
```

Comment: These still don't quite work, because of nested quotes in the `cut` command's argument. In the first case, escaping them (`... cut -d \" \" -f1 ...`) would solve it, and in the second case switching from single to double-quotes (`... cut -d " " -f1 ...`) would do it.

Comment: Oh, I pasted the original command and forgot to change the singe quotes to double.

Comment: I suspect it's all a moot point if you use the `--format` and `--filter` options to make `docker ps` output just the desired string, instead of using `grep` and `cut` to process the default output.

Comment: Oh, which @Phillipe has demonstrated :)